# Android Fql query Exception

Tags: android, facebook

I am new in Facebook SDK. I want to get PostID and Message from facebook. This is my android code.

```
private void Fql() {
    String fqlQuery = "SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id='100008169074385' ";
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", params, HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                     MessageBox(response.toString());
                }
            });
    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
}
```

but is Code gives me an exception:"an access token is required to request this resource".
Please anyone give me some solution

Comment: Seems like your session is not valid, because apparantly there's no Access Token added to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

```
private void Fql() {


        String fql = "SELECT link_id, title, summary, url from link WHERE  owner = 'YourID'";

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

        parameters.putString("query", fql);
        parameters.putString("method", "fql.query");



        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        parameters.putString("access_token",  session.getAccessToken());

        String response = null;
        try {
            response = fb.request(parameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        MessageBox(response);

    }
```